# HTML5 input type color value question

Tags: html

what values can the input type color have? can some one give a detailed explanation in layman's terms?

Answer (score 2):

So far, only Opera has implemented input type="color" and the value that gets used after a user has picked a color is the hex value of the color.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html#type-color

Update: Edge, Opera and Firefox implemented this already.

Comment: Today, FF and Chrome also support it. For most up-to-date information [go here](http://caniuse.com/input-color).

Answer (score 0):

`input[type=color]` supports six-digit hexadecimal RGB color e.g. `#000000`

ref: http://www.mathsisfun.com/hexadecimal-decimal-colors.html